# Mysql: Insert statement in a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, insert-select

I have the following table schema:

**Table_1 :**

Id(PK, autoIncrement)

Name

**Table_2 :**

Table1_Id

Table3_Id

**Table_3 :**

Id (PK, autoIncrement)

Table_2 has combination of Ids of Table_1 and Table_3 as its primary key. I need to insert values in Table_2 and Table_3 for all rows of Table_1. I am trying something like :

```
Insert into Table_2(Table1_Id) Select Table_1.Id from Table_1
```

But My problem is Table_1 and Table_3 have no direct relation and Table_2 needs Id of Table_3. Is it possible to Insert and get the new Id from table_3 within the above query(insert into Table_2) ? Please suggest a way to achieve this using mysql query only.

Below is the idea of something that if possible could have helped. Please ignore the syntax here:

```
Insert into Table_2(Table1_Id, Table3_Id) Select Table_1.Id, (Insert into Table_3 values (some_values..)) from Table_1
```

(If the inner insert query would have returned newly added Id )

To explain further here is a rough example:

Currently table 1 have a and b, now i want to add new x and y in table 3. And then table 2 will have 2 rows with a,x and b,y. A & x are linked but through table 2. And for now only table 1 has rows, other two tables are empty

Please let me know if i am not clear here explaining the problem.

Comment: Currently table 1 have a and b, now i want to add new x and y in table 3. And then table 2 will have 2 rows with a,x and b,y. A & x are linked but through table 2. And for now only table 1 has rows, other two tables are empty

Comment: they can have in future but for now i need table 3 to have one row per row in table 1. Its kind of a back-fill where i need to fill data in these tables one time.

Comment: table 1 is like user table and table 3 is address table. So i need query to set one address per user.

Comment: OK, I tried. Forget it.

Comment: np, thanks for your time.